# What does it mean? "That reminds me that you paid for something else."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I bought some clothes for her.
1 hour later, she sent a text to me.
Thank you for buying these clothes.
"That reminds me that you paid for something else."

What did she mean by that? She thinks that I have a purpose to do something? or she tries to pay me back instead money?

Comment: Can you tell us more about what happened (give us more context)?

Comment: There is not enough information to know what she meant.  Any answer would have to be a guess.

Comment: People do not always speak or text carefully. What is the situation?

Answer (score 2):

It literally means that she remembered that you (previously) paid for something else she received. There is a slight implication that she might owe you repayment for that purchase, or at least a comparable gift.

Without further context, it's impossible to be certain, but I assume it is a reference to an earlier time when you bought something for her, or perhaps paid for a meal.